# Why isn't my image row spanning the full col-md-10 width?

Tags: css, html, image, row

I have a row of images set to col-md-10 but rows aren't spanning the full width of the col-md-10. There's a little bit of padding around its right and left edges and I don't know where it's coming from. Can anyone help?

[The edge of the image should align with the edge of the red container below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K427B.png)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-ms-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                    <!--can be overflow row of assets-->
                    <div class="row screensRow1">
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen1.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen2.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen3.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-ms-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                    <!--can be overflow row of assets-->
                    <div class="row screensRow2">
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen4.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen5.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                        <%= image_tag 'Screen6.png', class: 'img-responsive col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.screensRow1{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.screensRow2{
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: you must be using boostrap, and the grid system has a padding in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

From [Bootstrap Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or    .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding.    That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via
>     negative margin on .rows.